# Is there some kind of hack that I can do to upgrade my Apache openssl from 0.9.8 to 1.1.1 ? Perhaps implement / recompile my own mod_ssl.so module?

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, ssl, https

I'm in desperate need for help. I've purchased a SSL certificate but my Apache server is running an old version of OpenSSL. **Unfortunately I cannot re-install or re-compile Apache.** It was installed through `apt-get install apache2` a long time ago, not by me. It has a huge amount of configurations, modules, websites, etc. not done by me, so recompiling and re-installing from scratch is not an option :( My only salvation is to really fix its openssl problem.

Apache is running OpenSSL version **0.9.8 which does not support TLS 1.2**. And without TLS1.2 **I cannot use HTTPS for my customer website** The browsers won't accept it :(

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe97df0000)
    libssl.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007fab1bf06000)
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00007fab1bb77000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fab1b95a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fab1b592000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fab1b38e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fab1b176000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fab1c387000)
```

But my Ubuntu box has the latest OpenSSL installed:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
```

I'm looking for some kind of hack that would allow `mod_ssl` pick up the latest openssl from the operating system.

Tried everything, looked everywhere, but no luck :( This will required a smart/bright/out-of-the-box solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even if linking the code to a newer version of openssl would work (likely not) the resulting binary would have no knowledge of the abilities of the newer openssl version. This means even though the underlying library would support TLS 1.2 the Apache binary would not be able to make use of it.

Comment: Any workaround? :| I mean, can I create my own mod_ssl?

Comment: @RichardBrason: If the version of Apache and mod_ssl is new enough to support TLS 1.2 with openssl then you can compile all of this and keep the configuration. It might though that your version of Apache is too old for this.